# how to detect server allow multiple part download QT

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem in writing my download manager.

How can I detect, if the server allow a multiple part download, when I am sending a request to a server?

How can I tell a Server, to allow one client to have more than one connection at a time and get information from the head server return?

Comment: From your question it is unclear what you are trying to do. What protocols, what request, what server? Are you trying to determine whether a web server (HTTP) supports/sends MIME multipart downloads? Or are you talking about chunked transfers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make request to server, server response might contain "Accept-Ranges" header. This indicates that server is supporting multipart download. More information [here.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

You can also send request without checking this header. If you want to download some particular part you need to set "Range" header. However is server does not support it, download may start from beginning. More information [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35).

Your Qt code might look like below.

```
    mCurrentRequest = QNetworkRequest(url);
    QByteArray rangeHeaderValue = "bytes=" + QByteArray::number(mDownloadSizeAtPause) + "-";
    mCurrentRequest.setRawHeader("Range",rangeHeaderValue);

    download(mCurrentRequest);
```

full working code can be found [here](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.kr/2011/07/simple-download-manager-with-pause.html).